# property does not exist on type [] typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hey I am trying to loop through an array and find a match to a value however I am having some typescript issues. When using the findIndex function to depict if there is a match in my array I am receiving the following error.

> Property 'continents' does not exist on type 'Main[]'

Not exactly sure what's going on here, I am guessing something is wrong with my mapping.

Interfaces:

```
 interface Main {
  continents: Array<Continents>;
}

interface Continents {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  countries?: Array<Countries>;
}

interface Countries {
  name: string;
  url: string;
  states: string | null;
  featuredCities: Array<Cities>;
}

interface Cities {
  name: string;
  url: string;
}
```

State:

```
  const [staticLocationHierarchy, setStaticLocationHierarchy] = useState<Array<Main>>([]);
```

Business Logic:

```
const checkOne = staticLocationHierarchy?.continents.findIndex(
  continents => continents.url === test
);
```

Comment: `Main[]` is an _array_ of `Main`s, arrays don't have a `continents` property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the value you are looking for however, you need to start by cleaning some variables, making your code clean will help typescript know what you want. I just removed and rename some variable I hope it'll help

```
 interface Continent {
      name: string;
      url: string;
      country?: Country[];
    }
    
    interface Country {
      name: string;
      url: string;
      states: string | null;
      featuredCity: City[];
    }
    
    interface City {
      name: string;
      url: string;
    }
    
    
    const [staticLocationHierarchy, setStaticLocationHierarchy] = useState<Continent[]>([]);
    
    const checkOne = staticLocationHierarchy.filter((continent, index) => {
        return continent.url = test
    })
```